# Unix command to know what applications run on a machine

Tags: shell, unix

Does it exist a UNIX shell command that you can use to know what applications (e.g. an Oracle DB, an Exchange srv ...) are running on a computer other than the one you are issuing the command from ? I mean a command whose output lists apps like those I mentioned above that run on a machine.

Comment: `top` shows running applications.

Comment: can an Exchange server run on a linux?

Comment: Thank you to you too, sozkul. Very helpful of you. Kent, you are right, I just meant to give examples, hints of major apps, not to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ps aux` to see what processes are running on the machine.

`top` is a slightly more friendly alternative (it shows also CPU and mem usage amongs others)

Comment: Thank you very much, krzyk, I used profitably the commands. Thank you again.